# Out of Memory exception handling?

Tags: android, exception

have a dump_log which points to "Out of Memory exception". How do I fix the issue as we have a number of applications running on the Android target?

Answer (score 1):

Each app has a fixed limit of RAM it can use, so the problem is in your application. You are either using too much memory or leaking memory.

Comment: How to figure out which application is leaking memory? So that I can profile that application and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no safe way to handle an 'Out of Memory' exception.  This is one of those exception that is critical and just is.  You need to figure out why you are running out of memory.  I would profile your application and see why you are using so much memory.